# Custom validator for backbone.js validation

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js, playframework, coffeescript

I'm using Backbone.js with [backbone.validation plugin](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation) to build a [custom validator](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation#named-method-validator) that checks if the email address (entered in a form input) is already taken.

The new validator is called emailAvailable and you can see below:
(notice: it's Coffescript, but at the bottom you'll find the code converted to standard javascript)

```
# ==================================
#           MODELS 
# ==================================    
User = Backbone.Model.extend(

    urlRoot: "/user"

    validation:
        email:
            fn: "emailAvailable"

    emailAvailable: (value, attr, computedState) ->
       // Ajax call to server (Play framework 2.2.1): returns the string "email available" if it doesn't find the email and returns the email address if it find it
       checkEmail = $.ajax(jsRoutes.controllers.Signup.isEmailExists(value)) 
       checkEmail.done (msg) ->
         emailFound = msg
         if value is emailFound
           return "already taken"

       return
)

# ==================================
#           VIEWS 
# ==================================    
SignUpView = Backbone.View.extend(
    initialize: ->
        Backbone.Validation.bind(this)

    el: "body"

    events:
        "change     input"     :    "validateInput"

    validateInput: (event) ->
        input = $(event.currentTarget)
        inputName = event.currentTarget.name 
        inputValue = input.val()

        this.model.set(inputName, inputValue)
        if this.model.isValid(inputName)
            input.removeClass "error"
            input.addClass "valid"
        else
            input.removeClass "valid"
            input.addClass "error"
...
```

This doesn't work and I can't get why. Where am I wrong?

**EDIT**: code converted to javascript

```
var SignUpView, User;

User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: "/user",
  validation: {
    email: {
      fn: "emailAvailable"
    }
  },
  emailAvailable: function(value, attr, computedState) {
    var checkEmail;
    checkEmail = $.ajax(jsRoutes.controllers.Signup.isEmailExists(value));
    checkEmail.done(function(msg) {
      var emailFound;
      emailFound = msg;
      if (value === emailFound) {
        return "already taken";
      }
    });
  }
});

SignUpView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    return Backbone.Validation.bind(this);
  },
  el: "body",
  events: {
    "change     input": "validateInput"
  },
  validateInput: function(event) {
    var input, inputName, inputValue;
    input = $(event.currentTarget);
    inputName = event.currentTarget.name;
    inputValue = input.val();
    this.model.set(inputName, inputValue);
    if (this.model.isValid(inputName)) {
      input.removeClass("error");
      return input.addClass("valid");
    } else {
      input.removeClass("valid");
      return input.addClass("error");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: That isn't JavaScript, please fix the tags.

Comment: Look at the edit, I've converted the code to javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backbone.Validation sadly doesn't support asynchronous validation functions. This is basically limitation of default backbone validation flow. It was designed with only synchronous way of validation in mind.

You have basically 2 options:

- specify async:false option for ajax call
- implement your own validation flow for this case

I personally would go with option 2, since synchronous ajax calls will lock browser until call is completed.

**Update note:**

I did quick google search after I answered this question, and it looks like there is extension for Backbone.Validation, which allows asynch validation. Please note, that I haven't used, nor tested it in any way :)

Link: https://github.com/suevalov/async.backbone.validation

Comment: This async validation plugin looks promising, but how to configure backbone validation to use it? The docs just links back to backbone validation.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do your async validation function yourself. Here is how you can do it without any plugins, just a little logic and good old coding.

1) Let's start where your function that will save your model is. You will need a Deferred object, like this, before saving happens:

```
this.asyncValidation = $.Deferred();
```

2) Then you will have to manually call your own custom validate function:

```
this.model.asyncValidate();
```

3) Then you will have to wait until your async validation is done. Once it's done, just save your model:

```
$.when(this.checkDuplicatesFinished).done(function () {
```

4) Check your own model attribute that has the result of your own async validation:

```
if (self.model.asyncValidateOK) {
```

5) Save your model:

```
self.model.save();
```

Here is the code altogether:

```
this.asyncValidation = $.Deferred();
this.model.asyncValidate(asyncValidation);
var self = this; 

$.when(this.checkDuplicatesFinished).done(function () { 
    if (self.model.asyncValidateOK) {
        self.model.save(); 
    }
});
```

Now, let's see your Model. Here is where the new custome validate function is going to be located. It's pretty much straightforward, you will need a boolean variable to store the result of the validation and the validate method itself.

```
window.app.MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    asyncValidateOK: true,
    asyncValidate: function (defferedObject) {
        var self = this;
        var attrs = this.attributes; // a copy of the params that are automatically passed to the original validate method
        $.get("someAsyncMethod", {}, function(result){

            // do your logic/validation with the results
            // and tell the referred object you finished
            if (true){ //validation ok (use your own logic)

                self.asyncErrors = []; // no errors
                self.asyncValidateOK = true;
                deferredObject.resolve();

            } else { // validation not ok

                self.asyncErrors.push(); 
                self.asyncValidateOK = false;
                deferredObject.resolve();

            }
        });
    }
});
```

For more documentation check http://backbonejs.org/, but there's nothing related to this. Hope this helps anyone that ends up trying to async validate.